# How to improve the speed of rowbinds when the size of the final dataframe is unknown

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, rbind

I want to rowbind multiple dataframes each with a varying number of rows. I understand that using a for loop in which something like a `final_df` is overwritten in each iteration is very slow as R has to keep a copy of every alteration. Usually, this problem can be solved by pre-allocating the correct number of rows and columns to the dataframe and then modifying it in place for each iteration of the loop. However, in my situation this is a bit more tricky as each individual dataframe may have a different number of rows compared to the previous one. (In my actual code I am dealing with a long list of XML files, from which I am extracting certain bits of information. Depending on the file, I can end up with more rows or fewer rows.)

My attempt so far is to use `dplyr::bind_rows()` or `data.table::rbindlist()`, which seem to be performing similarly well and both outclass `do.call("rbind")` by a lot. However, I notice that even with these approaches, the computation speed will still increase nonlinearly if I increase the number of dataframes.

Do you have suggestions on how I can further improve the speed of my code? Thanks a lot in advance!

```
create_df <- function() {
  nrow <- sample(12:15, 1)
  ncol <- 10
  randomdf <- matrix(rnorm(nrow*ncol), nrow=nrow, ncol=ncol) |> data.frame()
  return(randomdf)
}

approach1 <- function(n) {
  final_df <<- matrix(ncol=ncol, nrow=0)
  for(i in 1:n) {
    current_df <- create_df()
    final_df <<- rbind(final_df, current_df)
  }
}

approach2 <- function(n) {
  df_list <<- vector("list", n)
  for(i in 1:n) {
    df_list[[i]] <<- create_df()
  }
  final_df <<- do.call("rbind", df_list)
}

approach3 <- function(n) {
  df_list <<- vector("list", n)
  for(i in 1:n) {
    df_list[[i]] <<- create_df()
  }
  final_df <<- dplyr::bind_rows(df_list)
}

approach4 <- function(n) {
  df_list <<- vector("list", n)
  for(i in 1:n) {
    df_list[[i]] <<- create_df()
  }
  final_df <<- data.table::rbindlist(df_list)
}


microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  approach1(5),
  approach2(5),
  approach3(5),
  approach4(5),
  approach1(50),
  approach2(50),
  approach3(50),
  approach4(50),
  approach1(500),
  approach2(500),
  approach3(500),
  approach4(500),
  times = 10
  )
```

```
Unit: microseconds
           expr      min       lq      mean    median       uq      max neval
   approach1(5)   1173.5   1201.1   1317.12   1285.30   1402.2   1557.0    10
   approach2(5)    771.6    781.8   1121.18    829.15    944.6   3573.1    10
   approach3(5)    543.7    613.4    966.10    672.15    952.4   3131.8    10
   approach4(5)    520.8    586.5    641.18    621.65    663.8    818.8    10
  approach1(50)  12186.9  12381.4  13932.40  12760.10  14518.8  18537.4    10
  approach2(50)   6497.6   6766.0   7160.26   6967.55   7230.3   8390.6    10
  approach3(50)   3681.3   4143.1   4258.44   4233.10   4347.8   5022.8    10
  approach4(50)   3806.7   3821.8   4166.71   3962.95   4190.6   5900.4    10
 approach1(500) 275530.0 285779.1 326732.16 294302.30 304461.0 622130.3    10
 approach2(500)  65243.8  67456.7  72789.76  74422.30  77063.0  79485.0    10
 approach3(500)  38600.0  39328.4  41372.67  41215.80  42345.2  47488.8    10
 approach4(500)  32496.5  36788.1  41160.35  39940.10  46043.2  49752.9    10
```

Comment: Working with data frames, I think that's about as good as you'll get. If you could us matrices instead, that would probably be faster. I'd also recommend taking the "create the data frames" step out of your benchmark code, as that's an independent process. Yes, it's affecting them all equally, but it prevents you from isolating the step you're concerned with - the binding.

Comment: I will say, if I run `df_list = replicate(create_df(), n = 1000, simplify = FALSE)` and then `bench::mark(
  data.table::rbindlist(df_list),
  dplyr::bind_rows(df_list),
  check = FALSE
)`, I do not see `bind_rows` as comparable to `rbindlist` - I see `rbindlist` as about 4x faster than `bind_rows`.

Comment: (`bench::mark` might be nicer than `microbenchmark` in this case because it also shows you memory allocation, and it uses adaptive stopping rules rather than a set number of iterations, which means it's usually faster)

Comment: When I do isolate the data frame creation from the binding, I see `rbindlist` taking 1.31ms for 1,000 data frames,  31 ms for 10,000 data frames, and 494 ms for 100,000 data frames. So the growth is nonlinear, but less than 0.5 seconds for 100,000 data frames does seem pretty fast. At that scale, `bind_rows` is slower, but not quite 2x slower at 753 ms, so also very usable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`approach3` and `approach4` are spending most of their time in `create_df`, so you're not getting a good idea of the speed of the binding operation. Better to time just the binding:

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

create_df <- function(n) {
  nrow <- sample(12:15, 1)
  ncol <- 10
  randomdf <- matrix(rnorm(nrow*ncol), nrow=nrow, ncol=ncol) |> data.frame()
  return(randomdf)
}

df_list <- lapply(c(5, 50, 500), \(n) lapply(1:n, create_df))

approach2 <- function(i) do.call("rbind", df_list[[i]])
approach3 <- function(i) bind_rows(df_list[[i]])
approach4 <- function(i) rbindlist(df_list[[i]])
approach5 <- function(i) rbindlist(df_list[[i]], FALSE)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  approach2(1),
  approach3(1),
  approach4(1),
  approach5(1),
  approach2(2),
  approach3(2),
  approach4(2),
  approach5(2),
  approach2(3),
  approach3(3),
  approach4(3),
  approach5(3)
)
#> Unit: microseconds
#>          expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq     max neval
#>  approach2(1)   321.1   360.40   389.968   377.25   406.65   601.5   100
#>  approach3(1)    89.9   118.85   157.806   135.80   191.45   690.2   100
#>  approach4(1)    77.2    89.05   176.894   103.05   161.15  4250.6   100
#>  approach5(1)    61.8    70.10   100.532    94.15   120.60   223.7   100
#>  approach2(2)  3070.4  3228.40  3735.250  3352.30  3574.90  8796.5   100
#>  approach3(2)   348.3   408.35   470.308   440.50   514.70   931.6   100
#>  approach4(2)   136.7   169.65   204.703   189.25   222.40   362.6   100
#>  approach5(2)   111.5   133.85   194.793   150.10   199.50  2957.8   100
#>  approach2(3) 31565.1 34130.30 36182.204 35523.60 36503.40 89033.4   100
#>  approach3(3)  3008.7  3268.30  3785.467  3440.65  3714.85  7923.1   100
#>  approach4(3)   794.4   913.45  1009.823   966.20  1054.20  1692.0   100
#>  approach5(3)   655.8   767.35   870.240   822.45   894.95  2124.1   100
```

Now it is clear that `rbindlist` is the fastest for larger lists of tables. If your process is taking a long time, the binding operation probably isn't the first place I would look.

If you know the table columns all line up, you can squeeze a little more performance out of `rbindlist` by setting the `use.names` argument to `FALSE`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have many, many data frames, more than 100-150 this function is a good option:  `rbind_listdf()` from ***ecospace*** package it is very efficient given the scale.

If you are using a loop, then I would say if you can think about managing the memory within the for loop, it would help.

Using `gc()` as the final step in each iteration will clear out any large memory hogs before heading back to the next iteration.

If you end up with an intermediate dataframe, and can assign it a variable name, instead of creating an ephemeral dataframe that lingers in memory after binding, you can use `rm(temp_df)` followed by `gc()` to clear everything unnecessary out.

What becomes hard is when the size of the cumulative dataframe gets sufficiently large as to soak up most of your operational RAM then there is not much memory left to perform your binds.

In that case something to consider is creating a *.csv* file, and writing it to disk (saving it) and then using the loop to go throug your dataframes and write the rows to that csv, an appending action as opposed to opening, reading and saving. I would still use `rm()` & `gc()` to clean out memory before the next iteration. This may or may not be faster because writing is slower than binding, but it does mean not carrying that mass of the main dataframe in memory if you garbage collect often.

Once done creating the csv, you can clear out your whole workspace and then read in the csv or a database to work on the data.